# Conditional nested IF in R

Tags: r, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a column that contains some values as follows: 0 to 6
Each value refers to account type, whether revenue, expense etc

I am trying to use IF to look for the value and assign it its correct classification.

I have tried the following but it didn't work.

```r
account_type <- if(df$class = 0) {
  account_type = 'Suspense'
} else if (df$class = 1) {
  account_type = 'Asset'
}
```

I do appreciate your help.
I would also appreciate it if you combine an explanation.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

I guess that more preferable, R-ish way to do what you are trying to do, is to use a *lookup table*.

First, I create a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example):

```
set.seed(68826333)

(
    dat <- data.frame(
        account = sample(1:4, 10, TRUE),
        value   = rnorm(10)
    )
)

#   account       value
#1        2  1.17913936
#2        1 -1.40654534
#3        3 -2.46079924
#4        1 -0.20670095
#5        1 -1.29534910
#6        1  0.80030380
#7        4  0.37431903
#8        4 -0.07338782
#9        1 -0.50872642
#10       4 -0.15198686
```

Then I create a *lookup table*:

```
(
    lookup <- c('1' = 'Asset', '2' = 'Suspense', '3' = 'Revenue', '4' = 'Expense')
)

#         1          2          3          4 
#   "Asset" "Suspense"  "Revenue"  "Expense"
```

In my *lookup table* names of the vector corresponds to values of the `account` variable from `dat`.

Now, whenever you want to map your numerical data from `account` variable into *account types*, you can do just simple subsetting and reassignment:

```
dat$account <- lookup[as.character(dat$account)]

#dat
#    account       value
#1  Suspense  1.17913936
#2     Asset -1.40654534
#3   Revenue -2.46079924
#4     Asset -0.20670095
#5     Asset -1.29534910
#6     Asset  0.80030380
#7   Expense  0.37431903
#8   Expense -0.07338782
#9     Asset -0.50872642
#10  Expense -0.15198686
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used merge and it worked:

I created a new dataset and included the account types and called it class
merged1 is the first dataset that includes the full account numbers

```
merged2 <- merge(merged1, class, by.x = "classification", by.y = "class")
```

I am still willing to see more answers if there is an easier way, I am new to R and programming languages.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a dataframe with class value and name then using `merge` is the easiest way.

Here is another way using `recode` where you can specify from and to values.

```
library(dplyr)

df <- df %>% mutate(account_type = recode(class, `1`='Suspense', `2` = 'Asset'))

df
```

Comment: dplyr way is alternative approach.. can you show it using the base R way like the OP has asked?